# gocode autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: go, ide

I want to use autocompletion, but can't get gocode (https://github.com/nsf/gocode) working.

The editor of my choice is Brackets (using https://github.com/David5i6/Brackets-Go-IDE). But I can't get it working with vim+vundle or komodo either.

- The GOPATH wasn't set by the GO installation
- I set the GOPATH and PATH just like the instruction specified and can work on go projects just fine.

My folder structure:

```
~/Documents/goDev/bin/
                      test
                      gocode
                 /src/
                     github/
                            jonas/
                                  test/
                                       test.go
                             nfs/
                                  gocode/
                                       ...
```

From my .profile:

```
export GOPATH=/Users/jonas/Documents/goDev
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin/:/Users/jonas/Documents/goDev/bin
```

With go env i get:

```
...
GOPATH="/Users/jonas/Documents/goDev"
...
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
...
```

Is there something I did wrong with my setup? Or have I maybe missed something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe try to use sublime text 3 + gosublime.

Comment: gosublime also uses gocode.

Comment: I use gosublime + sublime text 2 and it works perfectly @J0-nas

Comment: FWIW I use Zeus + gocode and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your .profile and log out and back in:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
```

This got gocode working for me with LiteIDE.

Answer (score 2):

Often gocode is working correctly, but the editor does not find gocode.

Test if gocode is working correctly:

Terminal 1

- gocode close
- gocode -s -debug

Terminal 2:

- cd "yourworkspace"
- gocode -f=json --in=YOURGOFILE.go autocomplete 146

See results in Terminal 1.

If gocode seems to be working:

- gocode close
- start Brackets, open a Go file. It should start gocode in the background.
- Check if gocode is running: "ps |grep gocode"
- If not - check if Brackets can find the gocode executable. Path var, or add full path to Brackets config.